# VBA complex vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

Okay I saw a number of questions that were similar to mine but none were quite exact So the answers didn't help. Although it may not be exactly a vlookup the process is similar to one so that was the closest thing I could think of as a title.

I have a column (A) of values in document A and I want excel to go through each value and look in document B to find the same value in column (A). For each value it finds I want to do three things:

1. I want it to grab the value two cells to the right of each matched value found in document B and paste it one cell to the right of the value in column A of document A
2. I want it to look at the value three to the right of each matched value found in document B and if that value is "time" put the letter "T" two cells to the right of the value in column A of document A.
3. if the value four cells to the right of each matched value found in document B is > 5 I want excel to fill the cell three cells to the right of the value in column A of document A with a formula = the value of (column G / column H) in document B for that same row.

In case my wording was confusing I basically want to do a more complex vlookup. Document A has only column A and I want to look at column A to fill in columns B, C, and D using the table in document B

Please let me know if you have any questions and thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: Did you see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302824/continuous-loop-using-find-in-excel-vba/16339008#16339008)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the things you want to do starts out as a simple "VLOOKUP", but some have a twist. To simplify things, we should name the ranges "A" and "B". You do this by selecting all the cells that belong to "A", then typing a name in the address box (top left of your screen). Let's call it "RangeA".  Similarly, select all the cells belonging to region B (first column through eighth column; make sure not to include headers), and call it RangeB. Now we can begin:

> "For each value in A, find corresponding value in B, and return the
>   value two to the right":

This is a simple VLOOKUP. Enter this formula in the cell to the right of A (B1, probably):

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, RangeB, 3, FALSE)
```

Explanation: look up the value in Cell A1 in the range called RangeB. Find an exact match (that's the "FALSE"). Return the corresponding value in column 3 (two to the right). Drag the formula all the way down (shortcut: double click the little square in the bottom right corner of the cell when it's selected).

> I want it to look at the value three to the right of each matched
>   value found in document B and if that value is "time" put the letter
>   "T" two cells to the right of the value in column A of document A.

This is a VLOOKUP followed by an IF. Put the following formula two cells to the right of A (C1, probably) and drag down as before:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A1, RangeB, 4, FALSE) = "time", "T", "")
```

Explanation: look up as before (but column 4, i.e. "three to the right"). Test the value found. If it's "time", enter "T" in this cell; otherwise, enter "" (i.e. nothing).

> if the value four cells to the right of each matched value found in
>   document B is > 5 I want excel to fill the cell three cells to the
>   right of the value in column A of document A with a formula = the
>   value of (column G / column H) in document B for that same row.

Find the match, take the ratio. It would be faster to do the lookup just once with a MATCH function (in a hidden column on the sheet) so we have a reference to the row number (we need it three times), but it's not necessary. Unless your sheet has thousands of rows you will not notice the performance difference. According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771973/are-there-such-things-as-variables-within-an-excel-formula) there's no "quick way" to achieve this inside a formula.

```
=if(VLOOKUP(A1, RangeB, 5, FALSE) > 5, VLOOKUP(A1, RangeB, 7, FALSE)/VLOOKUP(A1, RangeB, 8, FALSE), "")
```

And there you have it. Note that `INDEX(MATCH...` (the preferred method of @user2140261) can achieve the same thing as `VLOOKUP` but it involves two functions. But if you decide to create a hidden column with the `MATCH` function in it, you can then use `INDEX` functions to achieve all the other things - and it would be the most efficient since you only use one MATCH (as opposed to recomputing it one or more times for each column).

I hope you can figure it out from here.

Comment: Wow that's a way better / more comprehensive way to do @Floris thank you once I get a good enough rep to upvote I will do so for you

Comment: @SeanConnecticut The reason I use Index, is because i feel the readability is there to know what Column I am returning as Value from, as opposed to the look up witch can take any range and a number of a column from the first column, this can get confusing, I like that the First part of the index is telling me what column on the sheet, not just the range, I am returning. That is all.

Comment: @user2140261 - your explanation for using INDEX is very understandable. I think that creating a hidden column with the MATCH function (which does the lookup just once and returns the row number in sheet B, then uses the row number for an INDEX formula in each column) is an even cleaner solution - but it seemed to go outside of the bounds posed by the question.

Comment: @Floris +1 that is something I do in practice a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX(B!$C$1:$C$15,MATCH(A!A1,B!$A$1:$A$15,0))
```

Goes in `B1` of Sheet `A` OR whatever `one cell to the right of the value` is and Drag Down

```
=IF(INDEX(B!$D$1:$D$15,MATCH(A!A1,B!$A$1:$A$15,0))="time","T",INDEX(B!$D$1:$D$15,MATCH(A!A1,B!$A$1:$A$15,0)))
```

Goes in `C1` of Sheet `A` OR whatever `two cells to the right of the value` is and Drag Down.

***NOTE: *** you did not specify what you wanted this value to be if `matched value found in document B` was *NOT* "time" so I just use the value in the cell.

```
=IF(INDEX(B!$E$1:$E$15,MATCH(A!A1,B!$A$1:$A$15,0))>5,INDEX(B!$G$1:$G$15,MATCH(A!A1,B!$A$1:$A$15,0))/INDEX(B!$H$1:$H$15,MATCH(A!A1,B!$A$1:$A$15,0)),INDEX(B!$E$1:$E$15,MATCH(A!A1,B!$A$1:$A$15,0)))
```

Goes in `D1` of Sheet `A` OR whatever `three cells to the right of the value` is and Drag Down

***NOTE: *** you did not specify what you wanted this value to be if `matched value found in document B is` *NOT* `> 5` so I just use the value in the cell.

This is if the values you are looking for are in `Column A` in Sheet `A`, and you are returning the values in Column `C:E` of `sheet B`

Answer (score 0):

First, my English is not good. Sorry. But I will try to help as I understand it.

A document contains the following information.

name
Sakir
Hasan
Hilal

B document in the following information.
Name    Index   Age Sex Column5 Column6 Column7 Column8
Sakir   8   33  Male    1   1   10  2
Hilal   6   20  Female  1   1   8   4
Nuray   4   22  Female  1   1   4   1

A document can write the following formula in B2 column.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2;[DocB.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$H$4;2;FALSE)>5;VLOOKUP(A2;[DocB.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$H$4;7;FALSE)/VLOOKUP(A2;[DocB.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2:$H$4;8;FALSE);"No Match")
```

Respects.