# Create Subtotal Row for Each Dynamic Range

Tags: xml, vba, excel, range

So I have this data in XML format that I use a Macro to make it look all fancy and break it out into dynamic ranges based on the group of data. What I want, and can't for the life of me figure out, is get a subtotal row for each dynamic section. It's starting to come to me as I write this out but I just can't get the code right. The columns will always be B:H and each section has a row that contains the word Materials and nothing else. 
Below is a screenshot of how my data looks like after I run the macro.
[image]

What I'd like is an un-boardered row under each of those sections that is blue, is merged from C:G, has the word subtotal in it, and then the actual subtotal amount in H. There can be anywhere from 1 section to many.

Here's what I want it to look like.
[image]

I imagine I could declare the dynamic range variable by looking for the word Materials then a xlToRight and xlDown. Then a For Each maybe?

I'm still learning so your help is greatly appreciated! Please let me know if you need more info from me!

UPDATE!!!

Here's what I've managed to put together so far. However, I'm getting the error, "Object variable or With block variable not set" on theRng = Range line.

```
theWord = Cells.Find(What:="Materials", After:=ActiveCell, _   
LookIn:+xlFormulas, LookAt _                    
:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 1).Select
theRng = Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(0, 4)).Select

For Each Item In theRng
    Item.Select
        With Selection
            .MergeCells = True
            .Font.Size = 14
            .Font.Color = vbWhite
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 51, 204)
            .Value = "Materials"
        End With
Next
```

UPDATED!!!

Here is what the data typically looks like right after I open it in Excel.

[image: data before macro]

UPDATED!!!

Here is the XML Data. Sorry about that!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Quote>
<Group>
<GroupLabel>Access Points</GroupLabel>
<LineItem>
<LineNumber>1.00</LineNumber>
<PartNumber>JX946A</PartNumber>
<Description>Aruba IAP-305 (US) 802.11n/ac Dual 2x2:2/3x3:3 MU-MIMO Radio Integrated Antenna Instant AP</Description>
<Manufacturer>Hewlett Packard Enterprise</Manufacturer>
<UnitPrice>$695.00</UnitPrice>
<Quantity>165</Quantity>
<Total>$114,675.00</Total>
<PriceList>USA Price List (USD)</PriceList>
<Status>Proposed</Status>
</LineItem>
<LineItem>
<LineNumber>2.00</LineNumber>
<PartNumber>H5DW1E</PartNumber>
<Description>Aruba 1Y FC NBD Exch IAP 305 SVC  [for JX946A]</Description>
<Manufacturer>Hewlett Packard Enterprise</Manufacturer>
<UnitPrice>$31.00</UnitPrice>
<Quantity>165</Quantity>
<Total>$5,115.00</Total>
<PriceList>USA Price List (USD)</PriceList>
<Status>Proposed</Status>
</LineItem>
<LineItem>
<LineNumber>3.00</LineNumber>
<PartNumber>JW327A</PartNumber>
<Description>Aruba Instant IAP-325 (US) 802.11n/ac Dual 4x4:4 MU-MIMO Radio   Integrated Antenna AP</Description>
<Manufacturer>Hewlett Packard Enterprise</Manufacturer>
<UnitPrice>$1,395.00</UnitPrice>
<Quantity>10</Quantity>
<Total>$13,950.00</Total>
<PriceList>USA Price List (USD)</PriceList>
<Status>Proposed</Status>
</LineItem>
<LineItem>
<LineNumber>4.00</LineNumber>
<PartNumber>H4DN5E</PartNumber>
<Description>Aruba 1Y FC NBD Exch IAP 325 SVC  [for JW327A]</Description>
<Manufacturer>Hewlett Packard Enterprise</Manufacturer>
<UnitPrice>$61.00</UnitPrice>
<Quantity>10</Quantity>
<Total>$610.00</Total>
<PriceList>USA Price List (USD)</PriceList>
<Status>Proposed</Status>
</LineItem>
</Group>
</Quote>
```

UPDATED 2/2/2017!!!

So I'm getting closer, I think. I found this, [continuous loop using Find in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302824/continuous-loop-using-find-in-excel-vba), and was able to get pretty close. However, I either get stuck in a loop, or it errors on the FindNext. I'm not sure what else to do! Please help!

```
Option Explicit
Sub Testing()

Dim wsI As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
Dim theWrd As Range, theWrd1 As Range
Dim theRng As Range
Dim theB As Range
Dim srchWrd As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 12 To lRow
    Set theWrd = Columns(2).Find(What:="Materials", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                 LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection _
                 :=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) _
                 .End(xlDown).Offset(1, 1)

    If Not theWrd Is Nothing Then
        Range(theWrd, theWrd.Offset(0, 4)).Interior.Color = RGB(149, 179,    215)
        Do
            Set theWrd = Columns(2).FindNext(theWrd)
            If Not theWrd Is Nothing Then
                 Range(theWrd, theWrd.Offset(0, 4)).Interior.Color = vbBlack
                    Else
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Loop
        End If
    Next i    
End Sub
```

The 2nd Columns(2) throws the 'Unable to get the FindNext property of the Range class' error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is XML an OpenXML format? Or a regular XML that you read into Excel per a map schema? Please post a few nodes (including root) of its content.

Comment: @Parfait I probably shouldn't have even mentioned that it is originally XML data. But since I did! :) I import the data as a Table. I then remove the Table formatting and convert it into a Range inside of the macro.

Comment: *I import the data as a Table*...what is a Table? Please qualify this with something: HTML table, database table, etc. What specific format is the imported content?

Comment: When I open the XML file in Excel, it gives me 3 options. 1)Open as an XML Table. 2)Open as a read-only workbook. 3)Use the XML Source task pane.

Comment: Back to very first comment, please post a bit of your XML to reproduce. And it is originally XML data.

Comment: does that help any? the XML is generated by a program that I use and I have little to no control over it.

Comment: Todd, I suspect that @Parfait is trying to suggest that the XML can be parsed via VBA and transformed into output structure with some techniques using DOM, XPath, XSLT or SAX. You really need to show the XML! <?xml version="1.0?><documentNode><product id="IAP 325"><materials> etc etc. Then it can be systematically transformed into reqired 2-D output.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. it has been updated!

Comment: Lots of practices to address including unqualified ranges, as well as the use of select (search for that important thread on SO). To fix your problem immediately: `Set theRng = Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(0, 4))`

Comment: ya, i know my code isn't right and i guess it is more psudo-code for now. i tried looking for the post you mention but haven't found the right one. i'm still learning so bare with me! :)

Comment: @MacroMarc found the post. thanks!

Comment: By the way, I don't  know any DOM, XPath, etc so was really hoping for something I could do in VBA. I am open to learning new things, especially if there is an easier way! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out. Thanks to all that tried to help! I still haven't quite figured out to actually get the subtotal math part done but I'm close and will work on that when I have more time. For now, this has been answered. See code below!

```
Sub findMaterials_SMS()

Dim cRange As Range, cFound As Range
Dim cFound2 As Range
Dim firstAddress As String

Set cRange = Columns(2).Find(What:="Materials", LookIn:=xlValues, _
         LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection _
         :=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not cRange Is Nothing Then
firstAddress = cRange.Address
Do
    Set cFound = cRange.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 2)
    Set cFound2 = Range(cFound, cFound.Offset(0, 5))
    With cFound2
        .Interior.Color = RGB(149, 179, 215)
        .Font.Color = vbWhite
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Size = 11
    End With
    With cFound2.Offset(0, -1)
        .MergeCells = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    End With
    Set cRange = Columns(2).FindNext(cRange)
Loop While cRange.Address <> firstAddress
End If

End Sub
```